# MSI GS65 8SE fans not working on Ubuntu

Tags: laptop, fan, msi

I am new ubuntu user and recently done with installing ubuntu on my laptop. I am facing issue regarding my laptop fans as they work on windows os but not ubuntu. what to do? any solution?

Laptop: MSI GS65 8SE stealth series.

Answer (score 0):

The fans by default are not active in any Linux distro, but there is a project that can activate them. See [is] in Github[1](https://github.com/YoyPa/isw). The project is mainly focused on arch linux, but it is possible to use it in ubuntu as well. See [this issue](https://github.com/YoyPa/isw/issues/40) explaining how to do it.

I have found this [this arch linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MSI_GS65) extremely helpful for all kind of issues related to this laptop. In my case I recently moved from Linux mint to Manjaro and I have to say I got finally the laptop working pretty well.